# How to add an effect with id on ngrx Store

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

It's my first time with Ngrx Store and I want to use it to get some publications from my database. 
I can do it for a simple publication but right now I want to do it but for a special id

This is my effect

```js
  @Effect()
  getPiinsByProfilesEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType<featureActions.GetPiinsByProfile>(featureActions.ActionTypes.GET_PIINS_BY_PROFILE),
      startWith(new featureActions.GetPiinsByProfile()),
      switchMap(action => this.dataService.GetPiinsByProfile(action.id)
        .pipe(
          map(items => new featureActions.GetPiinsByProfileSuccess(items.results)),
          catchError(error =>
            observableOf(new featureActions.GetPiinsByProfileFail(error))
          )
        )
      )
    );
```

This is my service

```js
  GetPiinsByProfile(id: string): Observable<ListPiinsResponse> {
    const limit = '7';
    const page = '1';

    return this.http.get<ListPiinsResponse>(`${this.baseUrl}/piins/profile/${id}`, {
      params: {
        limit: limit, page
      }
    });
  }
```

And this is my action

```js
export class GetPiinsByProfile implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.GET_PIINS_BY_PROFILE;
  constructor(public id: String) { }
}

export class GetPiinsByProfileStart implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.GET_PIINS_BY_PROFILE_START;
}

export class GetPiinsByProfileFail implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.GET_PIINS_BY_PROFILE_FAIL;

  constructor(public payload: any) { }
}

export class GetPiinsByProfileSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.GET_PIINS_BY_PROFILE_SUCCESS;

  constructor(public payload: Piins[]) { }
}
```

Thanks to everyone if you can help me :)

Comment: Still dont understand your question  ```but right now I want to do it but for a special id``` ??

Comment: Oh escuse me for my english. I just want to get the publication of a profile. That's why I need to call my function with his id

Comment: Do you have any error ? Can you call to the api ?

Comment: Thank you @TonyNgo

It's written "An argument for 'id' was not provided." for "startWith(new featureActions.GetPiinsByProfile()". But I'm not sure what's i'm suppose to do for the argument. 
 
And my service work perfectly when I try with postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's everyone and I find the solution.

I use the same constructor like @vishnu but the real problem was in my effect. 
That's my new version :

```
  @Effect()
  getPiinsByProfilesEffect$: Observable<ActionsPiins> = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType<featureActions.GetPiinsByProfile>(featureActions.ActionTypes.GET_PIINS_BY_PROFILE),
      startWith(new featureActions.GetPiinsByProfileLoad),
      switchMap(action => {
        console.log(action);
        if (action.type === featureActions.ActionTypes.GET_PIINS_BY_PROFILE) {
          const getPiinsByProfileAction = action as featureActions.GetPiinsByProfile;
          return this.dataService.GetPiinsByProfile(getPiinsByProfileAction.id)
            .pipe(
              tap((list) => console.log(list)),
              map(items => new featureActions.GetPiinsByProfileSuccess(items.results)),
              catchError(error =>
                observableOf(new featureActions.GetPiinsByProfileFail(error))
              )
            );
        } else {
          return observableOf(action);
        }

      }
      )
    );
```

And this is my new action :

```
export class GetPiinsByProfileLoad implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.GET_PIINS_BY_PROFILE_LOAD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component you have to dispatch an action to get publication based on id.

It should be like this

```
export class ABC {
    constructor(public store: Store<>,
               public action: PiinsAction) { }
      ngOnInit() {
         this.store.dispatch(this.action.GetPiinsByProfile(id));
     }
}
```

You also need to subscribe the result using selectors.

https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/ngrx-store-understanding-state-selectors